# ConfigureKestrel() conflict with appsettings

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have Kestrel section in appsettings.json and I also call ConfigureKestrel() in Program.cs. When I run the app, there is an error:

```
11:10:36 [Warning] () Overriding address(es) '"https://localhost:5003"'. Binding to endpoints defined in "UseKestrel()" instead.

11:10:36 [Fatal] () Unable to start Kestrel.
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://[::]:5003: address already in use. ---&gt; Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address already in use
```

Here is my appsettings.json:

```
    "Kestrel": {
        "Endpoints": {
          "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
            "Url": "https://localhost:5003",
            "Certificate": {
              "Path": "/tmp/localhost.pfx",
              "Password": "password"
            }
          },
          "HttpsDefaultCert": {
            "Url": "https://localhost:5003"
          },
          "Https": {
            "Url": "https://*:5003",
            "Certificate": {
                "Path": "/tmp/localhost.pfx",
                "Password": "password"
            }
          }
        },
        "Certificates": {
          "Default": {
            "Path": "/tmp/localhost.pfx",
            "Password": "password"
          }
        }
    },
```

Here is my ConfigureKestrel():

```
            .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5003, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps(o => o.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12);
                    listenOptions.UseConnectionLogging();
                    listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                });
            });
```

OR:

```
            .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                options.Configure(context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"))
                    .Endpoint("Https", listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.HttpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
                        listenOptions.ListenOptions.UseConnectionLogging();
                        listenOptions.ListenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                    });
            });
```

So, which is which? I am confused. Can I do everything in appsettings.json?

*Update*: I have figured out how to configure other options in appsettings.json except 2: `listenOptions.HttpsOptions.SslProtocols` and `UseConnectionLogging`

Comment: Have you tried to change port number in your program.cs?

Comment: I have figured out how to configure other options in appsettings.json except 2: `listenOptions.HttpsOptions.SslProtocols` and `UseConnectionLogging`